# How to instrument akka-http full response time?

Tags: scala, akka, akka-stream, akka-http, reactive

```
path("foo" ~ Slash.?) {
      complete(HttpEntity(ContentTypes.`application/octet-stream`, ByteString(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get("foo")))))
}
```

Say `foo` is a 1GB file. I added a `watchTermination` around the `Flow` of response, but I got notified **before the response is sent**, but in reality I would like to be notified **after the full response is sent to the client**.

Further investigation shows `watchTermination` is built on a `GraphStage`, which only supports `onUpstreamFinish`, and it's `onDownstreamFinish` is only called when there's an exception. See [GraphStages.scala#L128](https://github.com/akka/akka/blob/v2.5.26/akka-stream/src/main/scala/akka/stream/impl/fusing/GraphStages.scala#L128)

Here's the repo of my full code: https://github.com/ssgao/akka-http-quickstart-scala/tree/master/src/main/scala/com/example

Comment: You can add a oncomplete on complete future?

Comment: if the future we are talking about here is `RouteResult`, the `onComplete` is called before the response is sent to the client (unless it's chunked, in which case it's called before the last chunk is sent to the client).